# How to design a class with methods which have similar functions but different signatures

Tags: c++, oop, class-design

The task I have at hand is to write a system to test out `n` different algorithms in a library - all doing the same broad task but with different methodologies. I thought about creating a `main` class to which I send an argument defining the algorithm to be used. This `main` class in-turn calls the `taskAlgorithm` class passing on the parameter to be used and the required input parameters for the algorithm to be used. The `taskAlgorithm` class should then instantiate the specific algorithm class to be used in its constructor. `taskAlgorithm::Process` should run the algorithm and store the result and `taskAlgorithm::Result` should return the result.

I am stuck on figuring out how to write this `taskAlgorithm` class. In the constructor of this class, based on the `algorithmCode` parameter I want to instantiate an object of the specific algorithm, however, all algorithm classes are different and do not necessarily have a common base class. What's the best way to tackle this problem?

Specifically in

```
taskAlgorithm::taskAlgorithm(int algorithmCode, int argument1){
   if(algorithmCode == 1){
      //instantiate the algorithm1 object
   }
   else if(algorithmCode == 2){
      //instantiate algorithm2 object
   }
}
```

how should I instantiate objects for each of different algorithm classes if they don't necessarily share a common base class?

Comment: Questions about design and architecture are (a bit) off-topic for SO format.

Comment: If your algorithm classes have methods that expect THE SAME arguments, you can use templates. Why you cannot have the same base for all algorithms?

Comment: @Ron Should I move this elsewhere?

Comment: @Ptaq666 The library was written by someone else and I do not have the option of editing that right now. Also, the methods in algorithm class might have different arguments.

Comment: @TheBlueNotebook I guess Software Engineering SE or Computer Science SE would be a better match.

Comment: @Ron when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: @gnat Indeed. I left it out in this case given the OP's reputation and badges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they are related algorithms, perhaps you can think of the "common" interface that, if it existed, would be capable of calling into any of the algorithms if you knew which parts to use, or which transformations to perform.

This would allow you to write a wrapper interface to all the algorithms, so they can be called uniformly.  Each wrapper could "know" how to take its inputs to call the underlying algorithm that it wraps.  I didn't do it here, but you could do the same for the return value.

For example Algorithm A is a sort taking a pair of iterators into a vector of ints, and a comparator, while Algorithm B is a different kind of sort, taking a pointer to an int array, a length, and a comparator.

```
class Algo {
public:
    using Iter = std::vector<int>::iterator;
    using Compare = ...;
    virtual void call(Iter b, Iter e, Compare comp) = 0;
    virtual ~Algo() = default;
};

class A : public Algo {
    void call(Iter b, Iter e, Compare comp) override {
      algorithmA(b, e, comp);
    }
};

class B : public Algo {
    void call(Iter b, Iter e, Compare comp) override {
        if (b != e) {
            algorithmB(&*b, std::distance(b, e), comp);
        }
    }
};
```

Now you can wrap algorithm A with class A, and algorithm b with class B, and they are invoked identically, and the wrappers share a common base class so they can be used polymorphicly.

Of course, you can't templatize virtual functions so the iterator type is fixed, but the example here is about making a wrapper hierarchy that normalizes the interface to the algorithms.  Then you can avoid a nasty switch statement (which requires editing working code every time you add a new algorithm.)  With a class wrapper approach, just wrap new algorithm with a new wrapper class and it should just fit into any system that already works with the existing algorithms (provided you don't change the signature of the virtual call() function).

This isn't exactly answering your question but I think it's close enough to maybe be useful.  :)

Answer (score 1):

According to the comments under the question, I think in this case this is the only reasonable approach:

```
// structure of all possible arguments to all your algorithms
struct AlgorithmArgs {
    int arg1;
    int arg2;  // etc ...
}

class AlgorithmWrapper {
public:
    AlgorithmWrapper(int algorithmId, const AlgorithmArgs args) {
        if (algorithmId == 1) {
            algorithm_ = Algorithm1{};  // or whatever you do to construct that Algorithm1 object
        } else if ( /* etc ... */ ) {}
    }

    void someMethodToUnifyAllAlgorithmInterfaces1();
    void someMethodToUnifyAllAlgorithmInterfaces2();
    void someMethodToUnifyAllAlgorithmInterfaces3();

private:
    std::variant<Algorithm1, Algorithm2, Algorithm3> algorithm_;
};

taskAlgorithm::taskAlgorithm(int algorithmCode, int argument1){
    AlgorithmArgs args;
    args.arg1 = argument1;
    algorithmWrapperPtr_ = new AlgorithmWrapper(algorithmCode, args);

    executeSomeUnifiedProcedureCommonForAllAlgorithms();
}
```